# fancyimpute Python 3 MemoryError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a CSV file containing lots of missing values. I am trying to use 'fancyimpute' package to impute the missing values using 'KNN()' method.

The pandas DataFrame containing the CSV file has 7 attributes/columns while the 8th attribute which is 'time' but is used as index for the DataFrame.

data.shape

```
# (83070, 7)
```

data.isnull().sum().sum()

```
# 59926
```

data.isnull().sum()

```
'''
A        171
B        0
C        0
D        47441
E        170
F        12144
G        0
dtype: int64
'''
```

When I use the following code for data imputation-

```
filled_data_na = KNN(k = 3).fit_transform(data)
```

It gives me the following error-

> MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 filled_na = KNN(k = 3).fit_transform(data_date_idx)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fancyimpute/solver.py in
>   fit_transform(self, X, y)
>       187                     type(X_filled)))
>       188 
>   --> 189         X_result = self.solve(X_filled, missing_mask)
>       190         if not isinstance(X_result, np.ndarray):
>       191             raise TypeError(
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fancyimpute/knn.py in solve(self,
>   X, missing_mask)
>       102             k=self.k,
>       103             verbose=self.verbose,
>   --> 104             print_interval=self.print_interval)
>       105 
>       106         failed_to_impute = np.isnan(X_imputed)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knnimpute/few_observed_entries.py
>   in knn_impute_few_observed(X, missing_mask, k, verbose,
>   print_interval)
>        49     X_column_major = X.copy(order="F")
>        50     X_row_major, D, effective_infinity = \
>   ---> 51         knn_initialize(X, missing_mask, verbose=verbose)
>        52     # get rid of infinities, replace them with a very large number
>        53     D_sorted = np.argsort(D, axis=1)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knnimpute/common.py in
>   knn_initialize(X, missing_mask, verbose, min_dist,
>   max_dist_multiplier)
>        37         # to put NaN's back in the data matrix for the distances function
>        38         X_row_major[missing_mask] = np.nan
>   ---> 39     D = all_pairs_normalized_distances(X_row_major)
>        40     D_finite_flat = D[np.isfinite(D)]
>        41     if len(D_finite_flat) > 0:
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knnimpute/normalized_distance.py
>   in all_pairs_normalized_distances(X)
>        36 
>        37     # matrix of mean squared difference between between samples
>   ---> 38     D = np.ones((n_rows, n_rows), dtype="float32", order="C") * np.inf
>        39 
>        40     # we can cheaply determine the number of columns that two rows share
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in
>   ones(shape, dtype, order)
>       221 
>       222     """
>   --> 223     a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
>       224     multiarray.copyto(a, 1, casting='unsafe')
>       225     return a
>
> MemoryError:

Any ideas as to what's going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not that familiar with fancyimpute, however, using the pandas chunksize to iterate though, can solve memory related problems. Basically, the chunk size gives you a 'textreader object' that you can iterate over.

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv('my_csv.csv', chunksize=1000):
```

Another option, that could work, is import the data into 7 different pd.Series, perform your functions on each column, then concat (axis=1) to create a DataFrame.